# Flutter plugin with Firebase messaging callbacks not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing native platform Flutter plugin and I'm trying to get push notifications (through Firebase messaging) working with it but `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in the plugin never gets called.

I've added `addApplicationDelegate` to my `AppDelegate` and I'm getting `didReceiveRemoteNotification` triggered in `AppDelegate` but not in the plugin. However I do get `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` callbacks in both `AppDelegate` and plugin. I'm using Firebase messaging which might be messing up with this so I'm wondering if anybody tried this or might know what is causing callback not being called.

Plugin:

```swift
public class SomePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    ...

    // Add application delegate so that we can receive AppDelegate callbacks
    registrar.addApplicationDelegate(instance)
  }
}

extension SomePlugin {
    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        NSLog("****/ didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
        NSLog("****/ didReceiveRemoteNotification")
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) -> Bool {
        NSLog("****/ didReceiveRemoteNotification")
        return true
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    // set the type as sound or badge
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge,  .providesAppNotificationSettings]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

extension AppDelegate {

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        NSLog("**** didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
        super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

        super.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate {

    // when user opens the notification
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        NSLog("**** userNotificationCenter: did receive!!!!")
        completionHandler()

        super.userNotificationCenter(center, didReceive: response, withCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    // app is in foreground
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        NSLog("**** userNotificationCenter: will present")
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound)

        super.userNotificationCenter(center, willPresent: notification, withCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```